# Figure out initial balance for bank accounts to avoid them going into negative balance after transfer transactions

Tags: java, algorithm

I had to solve this problem yesterday on Codility as part of a job interview. At the end, even though my code passes the initial 3 tests, it failed most of the other tests (which are hidden) and it also failed most of the performance tests. And now I'm puzzled as to why and I was hoping somebody would shine a light on the glaring issues with my code.
Problem description:
Write a method that takes in 2 parameters:

- A string containing either "A" or "B" indicating the recipient of a bank transfer.
- An integer array containing the amount for each of those transfers.
  So for instance, if the String is BA and the array is [1,2], it means A transfers 1 to B, then B transfers 2 to A.
  This method should return what the initial balance for each bank account A and B need to be so that they never go into negative balance.
  In the example above, it should return [1, 1].
  Initial balance [1, 1].
  A transfers 1 to B [0, 2].
  B transfers 2 to A [2, 0].
  Final balance [2, 0].

Important points:
The input String and the input Array will always have the same length.
The input String will only contain "A" and/or "B".
I can't remember if the numbers on the array had to be positive, though I have not tested for negative numbers, so that might be a reason for the failure.

Other test scenarios:
"BAABA" - [2,4,1,1,2] - answer should be [2,4].
Initial Balance [2, 4].
A transfers 2 to B [0, 6].
B transfers 4 to A [4, 2].
B transfers 1 to A [5, 1].
A transfers 1 to B [4, 2].
B transfers 2 to A [6, 0].

"ABAB" - [10, 5, 10, 15] answer should be [0, 15].
"B" - [100] - answer should be [100,0].
"AB" - [3, 3] - answer should be [0,3].

My code

````
public class Bank {
    public int[] solution(String R, int[] V) {
        int aInitial = 0;
        int bInitial = 0;

        int aBalance = 0;
        int bBalance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < R.length(); i++) {
            char destination = R.charAt(i);
            int amount = V[i];
            if (destination == 'A') {
                int remaining = bBalance - amount;
                if (remaining < 0) {
                    bInitial += Math.abs(remaining);
                    bBalance = 0;
                }
                aBalance += amount;
            } else if (destination == 'B') {
                int remaining = aBalance - amount;
                if (remaining < 0) {
                    aInitial += Math.abs(remaining);
                    aBalance = 0;
                }
                bBalance += amount;
            }
        }

        return new int[] {aInitial, bInitial};
    }
}
```
````

Comment: If the code was only failing due to time limit exceeded this question would probably be on topic. Since the code isn't working as intended the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your solution appears to be that B's balance doesn't change when B makes a transfer out of their account and B had a high enough starting balance to do so. And vice versa for A.

You can simplify by simulating all the transfers starting from a zero balance, and keep track of the lowest (most negative) balance that was reached. Then negate it to get the starting balance that would have given a zero balance at that point instead.

```java
    public int[] solution(String recipients, int[] amounts) {
        int minA = 0;
        int minB = 0;

        int balA = 0;
        int balB = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length(); i++) {
            if (recipients.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                balA += amounts[i];
                balB -= amounts[i];
                if (balB < minB) {
                    minB = balB;
                }
            } else if (recipients.charAt(i) == 'B') {
                balB += amounts[i];
                balA -= amounts[i];
                if (balA < minA) {
                    minA = balA;
                }
            }
        }

        return new int[] { -minA, -minB };
    }
```

Comment: LOL thank you so much, indeed that was the issue ‍♂️.

Comment: Can you help to find that kind of question?